# Does MCMC perform better than a random walk?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I have read about and implemented a MCMC sampling based optimization for one of the optimization problems that I'm facing.

It seems the "magic" of MCMC, and the "inefficient" behavior comes in when, the jump to the next set of parameter based on the ratio of the current and the last sample's probabilties compared against a random function. Unlike hill climbing, this seems to sample the distribution randomly regardless of whether it improves the optimization or not. I feel this is very similar to a random walk without looking at any criteria that improves the optimization.

What makes the jump to the next set of parameters better in MCMC than a random walk?

Comment: MCMC is more of an algorithm-framework with different implementations. You need to be more precise there. Let's take Metropolis-Hastings as implementation: this is a random-walk with some concept of annealing (combination of Simulated Annealing approach as metaheuristic and random-walk as local search). It behaves a little bit different from a pure random-walk, because the MCMC-concept gives some convergence guarantees. The concept itself is very different from other implementations like Hybrid Monte Carlo or the NUTS-sampler.

Comment: Ok. I think I'm referring to Metropolis-Hastings. Is Hybrid Monte Carlo, better, i.e. faster convergence? or is it problem dependent.

Comment: As always with hard problems: it's problem-dependent, but HMC should converge faster in general. But keep in mind, that is needs gradient information (where it's power come from). This makes the implementation harder. A software example is the evolution of [pymc2](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/) and [pymc3](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/): the latter is built on top of [theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) to obtain gradients and be able to leverage HMC and NUTS (default in one of the most used MCMC tools named [stan](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/11/30/stan-uses-nuts/)).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in MCMC algorithm, e.g. [Metropolis-Hastings](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01896.pdf) (or many others), there is a *target* distribution that the algorithm converges to. You can use it to sample e.g. from [normal](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/metropolis-hastings-mcmc-algorithms/), or [gamma](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/metropolis-hastings-mcmc-when-the-proposal-and-target-have-differing-support/) distribution, [circular](https://blog.abhranil.net/2014/02/08/r-code-for-multivariate-random-walk-metropolis-hastings-sampling/) one, joint distribution from a [regression model](https://theoreticalecology.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/metropolis-hastings-mcmc-in-r/), or even *much* more complicated ones. In case of M-H algorithm you have *proposal* distribution that is used for drawing random values that are accepted or rejected based on some *target* density. If you wanted to compare them, with using random walk instead of algorithm such as M-H, then you'd be drawing values from *proposal* distribution and accepting everything. With random walk you draw values that are *"random"*, you cannot use it to sample from some prespecified distribution.

Comment: May I know why it makes sense to compare the posterior ratio against a uniform random distribution, before making the jump?

Comment: @dev_nut I'm afraid that this is another question that would need independent answer: maybe you should ask it by starting a new question? Have you checked the links in my answer? They describe and illustrate how and why M-H works.